# How can I get the ansible facts of my local machine in a json?

Tags: python, ansible

I'm trying to gather the facts from my local machine using `ansible_runner`:

```
import ansible_runner, json


res = ansible_runnner.run(
    module='setup',
    host_pattern='localhost',
)
json.loads(res.stdout.read())
```

But the `json` breaks because the data is malformed. I tried doing it with command line ansible: `ansible -m setup localhost > bla` and then changing the file and then trying to `json.load` it but still got stuck.

Is there an ansible built-in for this?

Comment: Considering that ansible uses yaml for all of its data file needs, doubt it. What does the output from STDOUT look like?

Comment: It is very json-like: "[WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available\nlocalhost | SUCCESS => {\n\t"ansible_facts": { ..."

Answer (score 3):

The output from Ansible isn't really meant to be machine-parseable. For example, the content produced by `res.stdout.read()` in your example includes ANSI color codes, which are nice for display but render the data invalid even if it were otherwise valid JSON.

You can access the result of the `setup` module in structured form (that is, already parsed into Python data structures) via the `events` attribute of your `res` variable.

For example:

```
>>> import ansible_runner
>>> res = ansible_runner.run(module='setup', host_pattern='localhost')
>>> setup_results= next(x for x in res.events if  x['event'] == 'runner_on_ok' and x['event_data']['task'] == 'setup')
>>> facts = setup_results['event_data']['res']['ansible_facts']
>>> print(facts['ansible_processor_vcpus'])
8
```

Comment: Yeah, I started with escaping the colors using `re.compile` but I'm starting to think ansible is not the tool for the job. For basic `ssh` commands, I think I'll go with `paramiko` for now